# Drive android.opengl.GLSurfaceView using Kotlin/Java code

Tags: java, android, user-interface, opengl-es, kotlin

I am trying to add an OpenGL surface view on a particular screen of my Android application.

I have the OpenGL surface view instance added to one of the activity xml files as follows:

```
<android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/flushOrange"/>
```

How can I drive this instance using code? I want to iterate the OpenGL screen through a set of colors.